# Prometheus counting issue

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to count how many value == 0 in past one hour in prometheus and try to create the alert rules.

I come up with the rules count_over_time(instance==0 [1h])/count_over_time(instance)

I got error shows I have to follow Prometheus aggregator expression.

Not sure what's the reason behind.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing out some mistakes in your query:

- `instance==0 [1h]`: [Range selection](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors) is possible only on instant vector, and not an expression. i.e., `instance[1h]` is valid, but not the one mentioned. What you need here is a [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery), and would look something like `(instance==0)[1h:1m]` (choose your resolution).
- `count_over_time(instance)`: [`count_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) takes a range vector, so can't use just `instance` here, which is an instant vector.

Now coming to your expected query, what I understand is you want to know what percentage of `instance` series turned out to be 0 in the past 1 hour and alert on it, for that I suggest taking help of `for` tag in defining alerts, for example:

```
groups:
- name: example
  rules:
  - alert: ExampleAlert
    expr: count(instance == 0)/count(instance) > 0.5
    for: 1h
    annotations:
        description: "Count of (instances==0) is >50% of instances for more than 1h."
```

Here if the ratio was `> 0.5 (50%)` for straight `1h`, it would alert.

Comment: Hey Codesome, I really appreciated your help . It works now